# Catching an undefined message in ObjC and forward it to a method with a different signature

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I'm writing a logger class (who doesn't ?) with a method

```
- (void) logWithTag:(NSString *)aTag andMessage:(NSString *)aMsg;
```

I wish to be able to forward undefined messages to this method. For example  :

```
[myLogger logFoo:@"bar"] should call [myLogger logWithTag:@"Foo" andMessage:@"bar"]
```

and more generically

```
[myLogger logXXX:@"bar"] should call [myLogger logWithTag:@"XXX" andMessage:@"bar"]
```

I've looked at `resolveInstanceMethod` and message forwarding, but from what I understood, they all expect the method to have the same signature.

Any idea ?
thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple covers this in the [`Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html). Basically you need to override `respondsToSelector:` and return YES if you would like to support the method. Then also override `forwardInvocation:` and then capture the selector string, remove the log prefix, and create a new [`NSInvocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that will call `logWithTag:andMessage:`

Comment: Thank you ! I also had to fiddle with methodSignatureForSelector: but it's working like a charm (apart from the compiler complaining about logXXX doesnot exist, but I guess I can live with that) !

Comment: Ah ya I meant to warn you about that warning, all you need to do is cast the logger as type (`id`). If your logger is returned by a singleton just change the return type to `id` there.

Comment: @Joe: if the method is not declared anywhere, you will get a warning that it doesn't exist, no matter what you call it on